# Why Command "cata/etc/..." does not give me any results?

Tags: command-line, cat, passwd

Why if I type:

```
cat/etc/passwd
```

or

```
cat/etc/shadow
```

the termnal give back me the message:

```
no such file or directory found ?
```

At least I should visualize me like user

Comment: don't you forget a space between `cat` and the following `/...` ?

Comment: great...yes it was my fault youre right....it happen to the apprentices like me :P. Thank you!

Comment: It should have given you an error message like `-bash: cat/etc/passwd: No such file or directory`. This is not what you told us - it's really important to be precise and complete

Answer (score 1):

Because commands must be separated by white space from the arguments.